# Can't remove vowels coming after consonants in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to remove vowels coming after consonants but code removes all vowels.

I don't understand why it would delete `"aaa"`.

```
def kk(phrase):
    v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
    for i in phrase:
        if i not in v and phrase[phrase.index(i)+1] in v:
            phrase=phrase.replace(phrase[phrase.index(i)+1],"")
    return phrase
print (kk("aaa bo cy da eee fe"))
```

Code above is supposed to give `"aaa b c d eee f"`, but results is `" b c d  f"`.

Comment: Your logic is clear: if a vowel appears after a consonant, you remove all occurrences of that vowel from the entire phrase.  You need to remove only the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replaces **all occurences** of the passed substring, so whenever you encounter an `'a'` for example, you will delete all of them:

Second problem, even if you fixed the `replace` issue, is that you are using [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index), which returns the **first index** found. So again, for example when reaching the `'da'` part in your string, the index returned for the `'a'` will actually be `0`.

To overcome this, you will first want to iterate over indices, create a new variable for the result and use slicing instead. Something like:

```py
def kk(phrase):
    v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
    res = ""
    last = 0
    for i in range(len(phrase)-1):
        if phrase[i] not in v and phrase[i+1] in v:
            res += phrase[last:i+1]
            last = i+2
    res += phrase[last:]
    return res
print (kk("aaa bo cy da eee fe"))
```

And this gives:

```
aaa b c d ee f
```

Note that one `e` was also deleted because of the space, this can be easily handled

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
def kk(phrase):
    v = set('aeiuo')  # for O(1) lookups
    deleteme = set()
    for i,char in enumerate(phrase[:-1]):
        if char not in v and phrase[i+1] in v:
            deleteme.add(i)
    return ''.join([char for i,char in enumerate(phrase) if i not in deleteme])
```

Method 2:

```
def kk(phrase):
    v = set('aeiou')
    i = 0
    while i < len(phrase)-1:
        if phrase[i] not in v and phrase[i+1] in v: 
            phrase = phrase[:i+1] + phrase[i+2:]
        i += 1
    return phrase
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo: thanks for the bugreport. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

For this task, regular expression is the better choice:

```
import re

s = "aaa bo cy da eee fe"
result = re.sub(r"(?<=[^aeiouy ])[aeiouy]", "", s, flags=re.I)
```

This solution assumes that the input contains only letters and spaces. If not, `[^aeiouy ]` needs to be replaced with an explicit list of all consonants.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

def kk(phrase):
    s = set('aeiouy')
    for v, g in groupby(phrase, lambda c: c == ' '):
        if not v:
            l = [(vv, [*gg]) for (vv, gg) in groupby(g, lambda c: c in s)]
            yield from chain.from_iterable(g for _, g in l[:1])
            yield from chain.from_iterable(g for v, g in l[1:] if v is False)
        else:
            yield from g

print(''.join(kk("aaa bo cy da eee fe")))
```

Prints:

```
aaa b c d eee f
```

---

More test-cases:

```
print(''.join(kk("aaaxaaa")))
print(''.join(kk("aaaxaaax")))
print(''.join(kk("a aax")))
```

Prints:

```
aaax
aaaxx
a aax
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so why this is not working is because of the `index` function being used along with `replace`. The `index` function will return the index of the first occurrence of the string, which is why in the example mentioned it returns 0 instead of the index of `a` coming after `b`.

One way to fix this:

```
def kk(phrase):
    v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    for index, i in enumerate(phrase):   
        if i not in v and phrase[phrase.index(i)+1] in v:
            phrase = phrase.replace(phrase[index], "")
    return phrase
```

Comment: Also the original code throws an index out of range error whenever the last char is not in `v`

Comment: I guess you meant a list, not array. And why is the code *assuming* to get that?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes I did mean list. I'm new to python so just getting used to the terminology. The last solution that I proposed was not the best so yeah..

Comment: Your code raises an exception. Please test it before posting. Your problem is that you are changing the string `phrase` while looping on its original items so you get a mismatch of indices

Comment: @Tomerikoo I have checked the code. It doesnt raise any exceptions for me

Comment: try doing `print (kk("aaa bo cy da eee fe"))` as OP and tell me what you get